# Unexpected Command Completion Code

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, acpi, gpu-driver

I am getting the error `xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0 ERROR: unexpected command completion code 0x11` on Ubuntu 13.10. The error occurs when I resume my system from being suspended. It also happens on my tty screens (`Alt + F1` - `Alt + F6`), but it will return when I return to my desktop in the case of the tty screens. In the case of system resume, I just have to restart my computer.

This problem began after installing `nvidia-current`, although everything that I have seen suggests this problem has something to do with USB 3.0. For my video card that is using that driver, it is an EVGA GTX 570.

Any suggestions?